# How can I update Gwibber to work with Twitter API v1.1?

Tags: 12.04, gwibber, twitter

Twitter deprecated v1.0 of their API on Tuesday and I'm curious to know if I can update Gwibber to work with the new API (given Gwibber's Twitter function has stopped working).

Would appreciate some assistance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fix in the comments https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1190575

Answer (score 0):

IMO there's no way to do this. Read what the guy this bug is assigned to says:

"Ken, do you know offhand if 1.1 is implemented in later versions of gwibber? Can I just SRU a newer version or do I actually have to implement twitter 1.1 from scratch here?"

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1190575

So the person who supports the package in Ubuntu doesn't know the status of the package development. I think we will wait for a long time unfortunately.